# Interactive geographic map in Phaser

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm trying to create a interactive geographic map with Phaser framework that is similar to this http://preview.codecanyon.net/item/interactive-usa-map-html5/full_screen_preview/4527698 so what I was looking into is loading tile maps from JSON or CSV, but I'm not sure this is the right approach.

I know it's abstract question but I just wanted to be sure I'm moving into right direction and see if there are other ways to do this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure a Tilemap is going to help you here. There's nothing 'tiled' or uniform about that map. While you could achieve it using Object placement in Tiled, I still think it's probably not the best route.

Personally I'd question the use of Phaser for something like this, and I wrote it! If I had to re-create the map you linked to, I would be looking at SVG and a library like paper.js instead, which just seems far more suited to this particular task.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware, but I was hoping there is a way to make phaser do this kind of thing, as SVG has very poor performances on mobile devices. For instance, Adding SVG image as a static map, and then having polygons layed over the image parts of each state and detecting intersections when user howers each polygon

Comment: SVG performance on mobile for something this simple would be fine. If you absolutely have to do it with Phaser, then I'd split the map up, so each 'state' is a single frame, combine them in a texture atlas, and use pixel perfect input selection to detect which one has been clicked on.